# Forcing an older package version in a Julia module

Tags: module, package, julia, version

I just finished writing my first Julia module and now I need to fix a package (Arpack) to an older version (v0.4.0, newest is v0.5.4).

How do I do this via my Modules code?

I currently tried this:

```
module DiffusionMaps

    using MultivariateStats: NonlinearDimensionalityReduction
    using Distances
    using Arpack: eigs
    using LinearAlgebra: Diagonal
    using SparseArrays
    using Pkg

    import MultivariateStats: fit, predict, projection, reconstruct, indim, outdim, eigvals, eigvecs
    import Base.size

    include("diffmap.jl")

    export fit, predict, projection, reconstruct, DiffMap, metric, kernel, indim, outdim, eigvals, eigvecs

    REQUIRE = raw"Arpack v0.4.0"
end #module
```

Honestly just what ChatGPT said, but when I updated the Arpack version and ran the module, it didn't force the version back down to 0.4.0. Is there any way to force that version downgrade or does the user just have to do it manually?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: If you write a Package (basically, a Module + metadata), you can decide the exact versions of dependent packages your package works with. Otherwise, just create a new environment and specify that requirement in the Project.toml file of that environment.